# Graphics with aChartEngine

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, achartengine

I'm trying to display an Android application which uses aChartEngine to create a line graph with fixed values.

But it seems that I have a mistake, does anyone can help me?

This is a class that uses aChartEngine to create the graphic:

LineGraph.java:

```
package com.example.anesthesia;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory; import
org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle; import
org.achartengine.model.TimeSeries; import
org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset; import
org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer; import
org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer; import
android.content.Context; import android.content.Intent; import
android.graphics.Color;

public class LineGraph {
     public Intent getIntent(Context context){
         int [] x= { 108, 109, 110, 115, 114, 118, 116, 119, 120, 125, 122, 124 };
         int [] y={ 75, 77, 80, 79, 82, 84, 83, 80, 86, 88, 85, 80 };
         TimeSeries series= new TimeSeries("Line1");
         for(int i=0; i<=x.length; i++){
             series.add(x[i], y[i]);
         }

         XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset= new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
         dataset.addSeries(series);

         XYSeriesRenderer renderer= new XYSeriesRenderer();
         renderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
         renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.TRIANGLE);
         renderer.setFillPoints(true);
         XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer= new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
         mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
         mRenderer.setChartTitle("Anesthesia Sheet");         
         Intent intent=ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, mRenderer);
         return intent;
    }
}
```

And this is how I call it, with the StartActivity:

> package com.example.anesthesia;
>
> import android.content.Intent; 
>   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; 
>   import android.os.Bundle;
>
> public class StartActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
>
> ```
>   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>
>   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>   LineGraph lg= new LineGraph();
>
>   Intent a=lg.getIntent(getApplicationContext());
>
>   startActivity(a);
> ```
>
> }

}

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your LineGraph.java is not an activty. To make it an activity, you need to extend the Activity class, so that you can call it using startActivity(). And regarding aChartEngine, there are many tutorials available online, which you can refer.

[Here](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Drawing-graphs-in-Android-using-aChartEngine-charting-library-(Line-Charts))

[Here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-drawing-line-chart-using-achartengine/)

Answer (score 0):

Looping from 0 to x.length will definitely throw you an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.You will want to loop up to bt NOT including x.length ...

**for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {**

...